# How can I check the number of command line argument passed in Perl?

Tags: perl, argv

I have a script that runs in the following way:

```
perl testing.pl -grid 24 -range 97   ## Here, arguments passed are processed via getopt::Long module.
```

Now, I want to check the number of command-line arguments passed to the script. Expected is 2. But I am getting 0.

I used below piece of code inside the script (testing.pl) to extract the number of arguments:

```
my $totalCmdLineArg = $#ARGV + 1;
print "$totalCmdLineArg is total command line arguments\n";
if ($totalCmdLineArg <= 0 ) {
    $defaultmode=1;
} else {
    $defaultmode=0;
}
```

Here, I am getting "0 is total command line arguments" as output. I would want "2 is total command line arguments" as output. How can I get the expected answer?

Note: There are 100+ arguments out of which any can be passed.

Comment: Before or after calling `GetOptions()`?

Comment: @shawn, After Calling getopt

Answer (score 6):

You can't count options after `GetOptions` has been called. `GetOptions` removes the options it recognizes from `@ARGV`. Quoting its [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.005/Getopt::Long#DESCRIPTION):

> The command line options are taken from array @ARGV. Upon completion of GetOptions, @ARGV will contain the rest (i.e. the non-options) of the command line.

Furthermore, `GetOptions` does not count how many options it parses. Check out the [source](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.005/Getopt::Long.txt) if you need convincing.

So, if you want to count how many options were passed to your program, you have to do it manually, *before* calling `GetOptions`.

If all of the arguments on your command line have the form `--option xxx`, then you can simply do (*before* calling `GetOptions`):

```
my $totalCmdLineArg = grep { /^--/ } @ARGV
```

However, this ignores the fact that `--` on itself in `@ARGV` marks the end of the option list. If your command line is something like `perl prog.pl --opt1 v1 --opt2 v2 -- some additional --arguments` then `--` and `--arguments` are actually not options (for `GetOptions`). To handle this case, you'd have to write something like:

```
my $totalCmdLineArg = 0;
for (@ARGV) {
    last if $_ eq '--';
    $totalCmdLineArg++ if /^--/;
}
```

However, this does not account for the fact that a single `-` can be used to start an option, and that this can be used to combine multiple options (is `$Getopt::Long::bundling` is non-zero). You'll have to adapt the code above to handle this case.

---

**Only in last resort** (do not used in production, might break at any time):
If you are using `bundling` and other complex features of `Getopt::Long`, you could hack a bit to count how many options `Getopt::Long` actually finds. Internally, `GetOptions` calls `FindOption` to actually find options. You could redefine it to count how many options are found:

```
my $opt_count = 0;
{
  no warnings qw(redefine prototype);
  my $original_FindOption = \&Getopt::Long::FindOption;
  *Getopt::Long::FindOption = sub {
    my @ret = &$original_FindOption;
    if ($ret[0] && defined $ret[1]) {
      $opt_count++;
    }
    return @ret;
  };
}
```

Note that this is a very fragile approach: `FindOption` is not part of the exposed API of `Getopt::Long`, and could thus change between versions, which could break this code.

Answer (score 3):

There are *four* arguments. Two is the number of *options*.

`GetOptions` doesn't provide the number of options found, but there's a nice easy and clean way to do this. First, use the `GetOptions( HASHREF, ... )` calling convention. Then, it's simply a question of counting the number of elements in the hash.

```perl
GetOptions( \my %opts,
   "grid=i",
   "range=i",
   ...
)
   or usage();

my $num_options = keys( %opts );
```

This solution works with all kinda of options (with values, without values, bundled, etc). It even avoids counting duplicates.

Unlike the earlier answer, this solution doesn't require reimplementing `GetOptions` in the caller (which the earlier answer does so badly, it claims the OP's example `perl testing.pl -grid 24 -range 977` contains zero options) or monkey patching the module.